# PHP strtotime weird offset error

Tags: php, arrays, strtotime

I have an array that is:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => true
  1 => "2015-08-26 08:42:51"
]
```

I can access `$arr[1] = "2015-08-26 08:42:51"` - However, if I do: `strtotime($arr[1])` I get: Undefined offset: 1

What could be causing this issue? The array at position 1 is set..

EDIT:

```
  public static function in_date_range($needle, $date_from, $date_to)
  {
      $start_date = strtotime($needle[1]); 
  }
```

And I call it from:

```
$date = $status['resource_completed'];

if(Helper::in_date_range($date,
   strtotime($from_date"),
   strtotime($to_dat)))
{

}
```

Where:

```
$date = array:2 [▼
  0 => true
  1 => "2015-08-26 08:42:51"
]
```

Comment: Could you please show the code where this happens?

Comment: What you are showing is working fine for me. Show us more code

Comment: Are you sure you have everything named right? Because it works for me.

Comment: @Smuuf Please see updated :)

Comment: You could extract the problem into the most light form: declare `in_date_range` as a function and not static method of some class and `$date = array:2 [▼
  0 => true
  1 => "2015-08-26 08:42:51"
]` is not valid syntax for declaring arrays. **This works:** http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/496a3565aafee37ce81cd8ef83a9c96701329cbc

Comment: @Smuuf Sorry - Why is `$date` not valid syntax?

Comment: Because `$date = array(0 => true, 1 => "2015-08-26 08:42:51")` or `$date = [0 => true, 1 => "2015-08-26 08:42:51"]` (since *PHP 5.4*) is a valid syntax. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: @Phorce what's this `$param("from_date")` and `$param("to_date")`? Is a anonymous function?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for declaration of an array is not valid.

You should declare array like this:-

```
$date = array(
  '0' => true,
  '1' => "2015-08-26 08:42:51"
);
```

Comment: Is not array declaration, is a dump from Symfony2 "dump" component;

Comment: Since the op expressed that the array is defined as such, this is a legit answer. Albeit possibly wrong, since the op expressed himself wrong.